# Centering problems

Tags: css, centering

I'm trying to make the page a with a horizontally centered image and some buttons under it.
I've centered the image using

```
.Image { display:block; margin:auto; }
```

That worked great!
I encountered some problems when I tried to center a button that was floating. I read, that it's impossible, and so resorted to using:

```
ul li{display:inline-block;}
```

and

```
body{text-align:center;}
```

It worked, but the 2 elements don't seem aligned. It appears that the buttons are a few pixels off. Here is the result:

[Screen shot of misalignment when using 2 different methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQJio.png)

I'm not sure how to center them properly.

Comment: `display: inline-block;` has *nothing* to do with centering anything.

Comment: well yeah, if you cant center a something floating, youll have to use that, then center it.

Answer (score 0):

**`margin: 0 auto;` doesn't works on `display: inline-block;`.**

1. If you want to use `margin: 0 auto;`, use `display: block` or `display: table; /* which is not good */`
2. and, if you want to go with `display: inline-block;`, add `text-align: center;` to it's parent.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
</ul>
```

---

**For more info**

[Center Things](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)

[Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](https://w3debugger.wordpress.com/2016/03/02/vertically-horizontally-centre-element-everything-you-know-about-centralizingcentralising/)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try:**

```
.Image {  margin:0px auto; }
```

If you have a div also....you can use this co-ord for centering.....